# SVG and Javascript - Creating a SVGPoint - TypeError: Illegal constructor

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to create an SVG polygon from with Javascript.

When I try to creating an SVGPoint with this Javascript code:

```
var p = new SVGPoint();
```

I'm getting the following message:
- TypeError: Illegal constructor

Comment: Hahaha. Safari: `TypeError: SVGPointListConstructor is not a constructor (evaluating 'new SVGPointList()')`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From your SVG document you need to call [`.createSVGPoint()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__createSVGPoint) to create a new point (initlaized at `0,0`), like this:

```
var p = svgRoot.createSVGPoint();
```

[`SVGPoint`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#InterfaceSVGPoint) (the interface itself) has no constructor, that's why you're getting an error currently.

Comment: Please define svgRoot and what type of element it is

Comment: @NuclearPeon: svgRoot is an `<svg>` element. The [`createSVGPoint()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__createSVGPoint) method is defined for the [`SVGSVGElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#InterfaceSVGSVGElement) element interface, i.e. an [`<svg>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#SVGElement) element.

Answer (score -3):

Also you can try to use Raphaël javascript library that implement alternative SVG API and can emulate SVG in InternetExplorer 6+: http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: -1 since instead of answering the person's need, you are trying to move them to use another abstraction layer. Not needed. FYI in 2019 I'm doing exactly the opposite: moving my svg.js -based code to native SVG.