# Create SVGPoint/SVGMatrix in unit tests or react

Tags: reactjs, svg

I need to do some simple svg matrix calculations while constructing an SVG scene in React.  For that I need to create an SVG point and matrices.

This is not trivial, as outlined in [SVG and Javascript - Creating a SVGPoint - TypeError: Illegal constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239405/svg-and-javascript-creating-a-svgpoint-typeerror-illegal-constructor/4239455#4239455)

The solution to the above question was to pick a svg-item from the scene and use that to create the points/matrices.

However, **what if you don't have a svg item?** Such as when working in React or in unit test?

I got around this by going:

`const svgElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")
const point = svgElement.createSVGPoint()`

Although this works - it looks ugly and does not compute in environments where `document` is not available.

Is there a workaround to this, or **is it really not possible to use these features without the mocking or outside the browser**?

(I now realized that these libraries might not be available outside the browser, but anyways...)

Comment: Any environment that supports the SVG DOM will have a way to create an SVGSVGElement.  If it doesn't support the SVG DOM, then it won't matter if you can create an SVGSVGElement or not.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I guess you are right.  I still hope that there will be a slicker way to deal with this in the future.